# Open a link in a new window

Tags: javascript, html, css

When you click on the link, the link opens on the same page, and the main link opens in a new window

If the primary link is https://www.google.com and the clicked link is https://www.youtube.com

The youtube link is opened on the same page, and the main link, which is google, opens in a new window, which is what the user sees when clicking

Comment: so... what is your question?

Comment: so window.open and window.location or regular navigation

Answer (score 0):

I hope these are enaugh for you,

```
window.open(targeturl, '_self'); //current tab
window.open($(location).attr("href"), '_blank'); //new tab
```